# Deserializing in Application Fails, Extracted Methods Work

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linqpad, xml-deserialization

Here's a weird issue.

I'm receiving XML messages over a TCP connection and receiving the XML message works perfectly, I've tested that, an XML message I receive is

```
<command><printreq><![CDATA[Printed text \r\n Second line with {012} code and <LF> code]]></printreq></command>
```

When I try to parse it in my application, I get the exception `"<command xmlns=''> was not expected."`

However, I've extracted the methods involved to LINQPad to test them and it works in there. So is there a hidden setting which I'm not seeing?

Here is the through XSD.exe generated code for my schema:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class command {

    private object itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType1 itemElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("printreq", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType1 ItemElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
    public enum ItemChoiceType1 {

        /// <remarks/>
        printreq,
    }
}
```

This is the method I use for deserializing a byte array (bytes are from UTF8-decoding the string):

```
public static object DeserializeFromXmlBytes(byte[] objectBytes, Type targetType)
{
    var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment        
    };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(targetType);
    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(objectBytes))
    {
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(memStream, readerSettings);
        return serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

And when I simply do this in LINQPad it works:

```
string xml = "<command><printreq><![CDATA[Printed text \r\n Second line with {012} code and <LF> code]]></printreq></command>";
var b = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
var o = DeserializeFromXmlBytes(b, typeof(command));
Console.WriteLine(o); // Outputs what I expect
```

However, deserializing in my application fails with the exception I mentioned.
Is there something I'm not seeing here?

When I hardcode the root element like:

```
var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute
{
    ElementName = "command",
    IsNullable = true
};
```

It parses without error, but the command is the wrong one. The resulting command has child-element `breakend` (also specified, but not listed in my code here) instead of `printreq`. This is getting weirder and weirder.

Okay, `breakend` is the first type listed as `ItemChoiceType1` so maybe it tries to do a 'best' effort kind of thing?

**EDIT:** I finally fixed it, it was a strange case of some compiled files remaining in memory or something, just deleted and recreated some files and now it works. Case closed.

Comment: Does that *really* work in LINQPad? because: that xml is invalid ... missing a `<` before `/printreq>`

Comment: Fixed that issue, was due to bad copy pasting/editing.

Comment: are you sure you don't have multiple types called `command`, in different namespaces?

Comment: the xml error is still in the example at the bottom, btw. The code as posted works fine. I can only conclude the issue is in the code that isn't posted :(

Comment: I only have one `command`-type.

Comment: All I can suggest is: use you application code to make a reproducible example. Chances are good that in the process you'll find the key difference

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to do.